# decrese the height of the menu in gantry wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, resize

Thanks in advance. for looking at the question.

my site www.ezensure.com is built on gantry wordpress template.

is there a way that i can reduce the hight of the the Top module position. so that the height of menu and logo decreases by 50 %. I paln a slim menu and logo.

Answer (score 0):

You can slim down the top section by overriding the CSS like this or similar:

```
.gf-menu.l1 > li > .item {
    line-height: 10px;
}

.gf-menu li.parent > .item:after {
    margin-top: -6px;
}


.logo-block {
    margin: 2px 10px;
}
```

To override the CSS, add the above code to a custom CSS file at `/wp-content/themes/[TEMPLATE]/css/[TEMPLATE]-custom.css`

The official instructions for adding a custom CSS file are at: http://www.gantry-framework.org/documentation/wordpress/tutorials/custom_stylesheet.md

Another option you may not have considered is to use the RocketTheme "Anacron" theme (or similar) which has a scrolling header that scrolls away to nothing as you page down, and reappears when needed if you scroll back up: http://demo.rockettheme.com/wordpress-themes/anacron